# Tiny transmissions end up meshed together, Do I really need to parse the buffer?

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11

I am doing some socketprogramming and I've come upon a little snag.

I've defined a protocol for communication between server and clients as part of a poker game, so when either side wants to trigger a certain action on the farside, it creates a array of ints(simple marshaling), where the very first int is the "opcode", a simple code that details how the data are to be used, as well as the size of the transmission. Any subsequent ints can be seen as arguments to that operation(where applicable), emulating function calls.

One thing the server needs to do whenever a client connects, is to notify the other clients that a new one has joined the game, so it sends a "new player has connected" message to all the other clients, which includes the tablenumber of that new player.

The problem arises when the serves tries to notify a client in quick succession, as my pseudo code will demonstrate. What happens is that the server sends two 8 byte transmissions that get received as a single 16 bytes(4 ints) on the farside. The result is that the client only passes on and uses the first 8 bytes, ignoring the rest, causing mayham(prints out a massive list of rubbish) later on when, for instance, the unlisted players say something in the chat.

Since I can't show my actual code, consider the following pseudocode on the relevant part of the serverside:

```
enum PROTOCOLENUMS
{
    NOTIFYPROTOCOL = //some number
}

//Reps is simple vector containing custom objects of type playerRepresentation.
for(auto player : Reps)
{
   if (player.getSocketNr() != newfiledescriptor)
   {

       int oldguyInfo[2] = 
       {NOTIFYPROTOCOL,player.getSocketNr() };
       send(newfd,oldguyInfo,sizeof(oldguyInfo),0);
       //the old players are simultaniously notified of the new player here.
   }
}
```

On the client side, the code responsible for receiving the transmission, and passing it on, looks something like this(error checking omitted):

```
short bytecount
while (true)
{
    bytecount = recv(serverSocketDescriptor,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
    cout<<bytecount<<endl; //Bytecount should ready 8 every time, instead it will accumulate if recv doesn't get called between sends.
    InterfacePtr->processTransmission(buffer);
}
```

Like I said, the problem arises when the buffer on the receiving side packs two(or more) sends into the internal cache, ie the tranmissions happen so fast that the recv() doesn't unblock in time to flush the first message out of the buffer before the second one has arrived. Thusly only the first transmission actually gets used by the subsequent processing function(IE processTransmission() ).

I guess it is also possible that the fault lies on the server side, which is to say that the underlying API sees fit to save some bandwidth by packing two small transmissions into one, instead of sending straight away. This seems unlikely though.

Now, what I really want to ask is this: Do I really have to parse the buffer after every recv in order to determine if there are more than one set of transmissions available?

Comment: There is no fault with the server, that's just packet coalescing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421848/send-data-in-separate-tcp-segments-without-being-merged-by-the-tcp-stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to so this kind of thing is to define a protocol.
A protocol is a formalised way of introducing each message as a logical unit.

Some protocols (such as HTTP) use delimiters (like newlines) to separate parts of a message (and the message itself).

In a game it would be more normal to have a binary protocol where each message is preceded by its length.

For example, one protocol you could adopt is that each message is preceded by 4 bytes which encode the message length.

Then your reader end would look like this:

```
while(running)
{
    int32_t wire_length = 0;
    recv(fd, &length, sizeof(length), 0);
    auto length = ntohl(wire_length);
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(length);
    recv(fd, &buffer[0], length, 0);
    // buffer now contains exactly one message
    // decode and dispatch here
 }
```

Comment: Interesting. If I understand this correctly, I can read less than the amount of bytes available in the stream. 

But what about recv? Won't it block?

And how about the stream? Does the read data also get removed from the stream? I mean, is the first message still in the stream the next time recv is called?

Comment: you can choose to use blocking or non-blocking mode. Once you start venturing into non-blocking async comms I would encourage you to use boost::asio.

Comment: and yes, you are allowed to restrict how much you read during each read. You will get *UP TO* the number of bytes you requested so you will want to check the return value to fill your message buffer appropriately. The example I posted was very simplified

Comment: ...and no, you won't lose any bytes. the socket buffers them for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, we can't see what protocol you are using - TCP(/IP) or UDP(/IP). If it's TCP, then the behavior you describe is expected, 'cause it's a "byte-stream" connection, data "just keeps coming in", and you read it "as much as you want/need when you want/need".

If you use UDP, then each message is separate (it's a "datagram"), there will be no "mesh up together", but there will also be no support for error handling (a datagram arrives or it doesn't, that's it).

So, check you socket creation code, if you can't make sense of it, share it.

UPDATE:

To help with messaging w/TCP, you can use a "message delimiting" scheme/protocol, like Async HDLC. You can look it up, but, in essence, you send 0x7E between messages (one or more bytes) and, if 0x7E is to be sent, replace (encode) it with 0x7F 0x5E (xor w/0x20) - of course, you need to encode also 0x7F, but could encode other bytes if you like (say, 0x00). Decoding is simple and can be done "in-place".

UPDATE 2:

If you're nervous about doing "reliable UDP" yourself, there are some libraries for that. I used UDT (http://udt.sourceforge.net/) on a significant project and it worked fine. It's interface is "sockets-like", so, it should not be hard to switch to / try out.

Comment: I use TCP, the idea of manually taking care of resending lost packets scare me.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes.  You want to consume as many messages that come in and discard the ones that are used so they don't get used again.  Also, you will have to take into account when partial messages are sent.  Given that you know the length of each message, the above two task should be straight forward.

Comment: I was afraid that'd be the case. Thanks for the help.