# springboot use http respose header transfer:encoding, but tcp send two packet even if the response is small

Tags: spring-boot, http, tomcat, tcp, http-headers

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class HttpChunkedApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HttpChunkedApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping("/home/getMsg")
    public ChunkedRsp login( HttpServletResponse response ){
        return new ChunkedRsp("aaa","bbb","ccc");
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
public class ChunkedRsp {
   private String A;
   private String B;
   private String C;

    public ChunkedRsp(String a, String b, String c) {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }
}
```

run the application, then

1. sudo tcpdump -i any  -nnAls0 port 8080
2. curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:8080/home/getMsg

tcpdump shows two data packet:
[tcp dump packet when I curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXy8q.png)

Comment: Questions are ecouraged to post a [Minimum, verifiable example](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is exactly how chunked encoding should work (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)):

- every chunk is prefixed with its length (in hexadecimal) and `\r\n`,
- the sequence `0\r\n\r\n` indicates the end of the message.

The number of TCP segments sent depends on your TCP/IP stack (Operating System). If the connection is **slow** and the `TCP_NO_DELAY` option is false, the segments will be **merged**: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8421848/11748454).

Tomcat by default sets the `TCP_NO_DELAY` option to `true` on the sockets (cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Java_TCP_socket_attributes)). To disable it, modify your connector configuration:

```xml
<Connector port="8080"
           socket.tcpNoDelay="false"
           ... />
```

and test your server on a real connection (not the loopback device `127.0.0.1`, which is extremely fast).

Comment: springboot will use chunked response when return an object.  if return a  string, response will not chunked.

Comment: Yes, it does. So your problem is not the two TCP segments, but the fact that Spring Boot uses chunked encoding? You should clarify it by modifying your question.

Comment: why chunked response will send two TCP segments ?  I find outputStream.flush() will send two TCP segments， but outputStream.write() will merge  two TCP segments in one.